# Is a function with an essential singularity always some composition of an entire transcendental (not a polynomial) function?

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

I thought about the theorem of Casorati-Weierstraß(in my lecture notes there are actually two, one deals with entire functions and the other with essential singularities) and asked myself if the following is true:

Let $G$ be a domain, $f(z)$ a holomorphic function on $G\setminus\{z_0\}$ and $z_0$ an essential singularity of $f(z)$.

$\Rightarrow f(z)$ is composed of a function $h(z) = g(a(z))$, where $g(z)$ is an entire transcendental function and $a(z)$ is a holomorphic function on $G\setminus\{z_0\}$ with a pole in $z_0$.

Comment: What basis do you have for this? What is your argument

Comment: $\tan\left( \mathrm{e}^{-1/z^2} \right)$, $\tan\left(\tan\left( \mathrm{e}^{-1/z^2} \right)\right)$, $\tan \left( \tan \left( \tan\left( \mathrm{e}^{-1/z^2} \right) \right) \right)$, ...

Comment: @Erich Towers: Could you be a little more specific about why $tan(e^{\frac{-1}{z^2}})$ is a counterexample to my assumption because I don't fully understand how the complex tangens behaves.

Comment: Yes. Recall that all polynomials are factorizable in $\Bbb C$, so singularities will be poles of various order.

Comment: the problem is that you can have  a function with a sequence of poles towards the isolated singularity like the tangent above which has a sequence of poles at infinity, hence if you compose it with any $f(1/z), f$ entire transcendental, will give you a sequence of poles towards zero for example

Comment: Ok, what if I change the domain $G$ in the assumption to a centered disc around $z_0$ ?